# Set format of data for serializer in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I have something like:

```
[DataContract]
DateTime date;
```

However, I have specific format of my date: `20170403`.  How to force WCF serializer to serialize such format ? At this moment it returns validation error.  How to do it ?

Comment: DateTime sturcture have no knowledge of the display format. Only string representations of DateTime have formats.

Comment: Send date as string. If you need you can have non data member property to get DateTime from that string (parse on get).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataContractSerializer` is going to follow the expected XML date format rules for dates, so if the other end isn't expecting that: you simply can't use a date. You'll have to expose it as a `string` instead:

```
public DateTime Date {get;set;} // note no serialization attribs

[DataMember(Name="date")]
public string DateString {
    get { return Date.WhateverFormattingCodeYouWantHere(); }
    set { Date = value.WhateverParsingCodeYouWantHere(); }
}
```

Comment: Could you be more precisely about : `WhateverFormattingCodeYouWantHere` and `WhateverParsingCodeYouWantHere`  ?

Comment: @HaskellFun well, `return Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd");` and `Date = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` would be my first guess...

Comment: thanks. Could you help here ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43501966/defining-some-configuration-using-only-app-config I spend much time and didn't managed to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 [Serializable]
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]

public className{
[DataMember]
DateTime date;
}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Sorry but it will not. This answer have nothing to solve specific format date problem.